# WPF Program designed on Windows 10 doesn't scale on Windows 7 correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I've spent the last few months creating a C# WPF program for a client running Windows 7. I've been developing the program on a Windows 10 device and recently sent the client a beta build to be told it wasn't functioning correctly. Please see images below:

[image: img1]

Windows 10 is the intended result. However as shown in the photo the icons inside of the MenuItem are their full image size instead of shrinking to fit the menu.
Code of Menu:

```
    <Menu Height="21" x:Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Panel.ZIndex="3">
        <MenuItem Header="_File " >
            <MenuItem Header="_Open" x:Name="Open" Click="Open_Click" >
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="Resources/OpenFolder.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
```

[image: img2]

On Windows 7 the blur effect will not apply to the grid. Code for blur:

```
    BlurEffect myBlurEffect = new BlurEffect {Radius = 10};
    HomeGrid.Effect = myBlurEffect;
```

In addition, there are also numerous buttons which are slightly cut off.

Any help in how to fix these problems would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd try just slapping them in a [ViewBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) and move on with your day. Or convert them to actual Path's or use something like Segoe MDL2 icons as a font style for easier scaling since I'm pretty sure all those icons are in there already.

Comment: I've tried "Slapping" it into a ViewBox and it didn't seem to make any difference. `<MenuItem Header="_Open" x:Name="Open" Click="Open_Click" >
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Viewbox>
                            <Image Source="Resources/OpenFolder.png" />
                         </Viewbox>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>` 
I don't understand what you meant by "Actual paths" and I can't use "Segoe MDL2 icons" because other menu icons are custom image icons that I've made.

Comment: Right so if you embed the image in ViewBox you'll need to specify the size restrictions either to it or its parent for Height or Width and Stretch method. Personally when I make icon assets I like to create the vector in Illustrator and then export to Path geometry so they're scalable and retain resolution etc, instead of using a raster image. Though you could just set your Height/Width on your image directly and expect it to keep its size as well. Except what's strange to me is I could have sworn thos sizes are hard coded on the templates ContentPresenter already and you shouldn't need them.

Comment: Oh also, your second question would generally be another individual question. Though I'd have to look at that one, been some time since I've had to backwards compatible to *<win8

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think for the BlurEffect you would have to set [AllowTransparency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency(v=vs.110).aspx) to true.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, I'm currently in the process of creating a Windows 7 Virtual machine so I can try out your suggestions faster. I'll update soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey thanks to the comments a solution has been found & encase anyone has a similar problem...

**Problem one** was fixed as suggested by using viewboxes and then setting a defined width and height of 15 pixels. The code is now:

```
 <Menu Height="21" x:Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Panel.ZIndex="3">
            <MenuItem Header="_File " >
                <MenuItem Header="_Open" x:Name="Open" Click="Open_Click" >
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                         <Viewbox Width="15" Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                               <Image Source="Resources/OpenFolder.png" />
                         </Viewbox>             
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
```

**Problem two** was fixed by running a Windows Update. My virtual machine did over 200 Windows updates so I'm unsure which update fixed the problem, but I believe one of the updates to the .net framework updates fixed the blur issue.